# Problem with comunication between .Net 6 c# APi and Angular

Tags: c#, .net, angular, entity-framework, rest

I have three function in .Net web api in .Net 6.

First:

```
    [HttpPost("name/{name}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Book>> PostOrder(string name, Book book)
    {
        try
        {
            var id = _context.Order.Where(el => el.User == name).Select(el => el.OrderID).FirstOrDefault();

            if (id > 0)
            {
                book.OrderID = id;
                _context.Book.Update(book);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                return book;
            }
            else
            {
                Order o = new()
                {
                    User = name
                };
                _context.Order.Add(o);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                id = _context.Order.Where(el => el.User == name).Select(el => el.OrderID).FirstOrDefault();

                book.OrderID = id;
                _context.Book.Update(book);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                return book;
            }  
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            return NotFound();
        }
    }
```

Second and third

```
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutUser(int id, User user)
    {
        if (id != user.id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        _context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!UserExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return NoContent();
    }

    // POST: api/Users
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<User>> PostUser(User user)
    {
        _context.User.Add(user);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction("GetUser", new { id = user.id }, user);
    }
```

And I use to communication Angular:
First:

```
addToOrder(user: string, book: Book): Observable<Book> {
 const url = `${this.orderUrl}/name/${user}`;
 return this.http.post<Book>(this.orderUrl, book, this.httpOptions).pipe(
   tap(_ => this.log(`added book to order for ${user}`)),
   catchError(this.handleError<Book>('addToOrder'))
 );
}
```

Second and third:

```
updateUser(user: User): Observable<any> {
 const url = `${this.usersUrl}/${user.id}`;
 return this.http.put(url, user, this.httpOptions).pipe(
   tap(_ => this.log(`updated users id=${user.id}`)),
   catchError(this.handleError<any>('updateUser'))
 );
}

addUser(user: User): Observable<User> {
  return this.http.post<User>(this.usersUrl, user, this.httpOptions).pipe(
  tap((newUser: User) => this.log(`added user w/ id=${newUser.id}`)),
  catchError(this.handleError<User>('addUser'))
  );
}
```

And first no working. No communicating with .Net, where is wrong data? I can't find any. Mayby parameters is incorect. But I do not see. Any other function working, I have responde and in debug the server is requested but on first request no. Only in POSTMAN or SWAGGER.

I have  in orders on Angular:

```
getOrder(user: string): Observable<Book[]> {
 const url = `${this.orderUrl}/name/${user}`;
 return this.http.get<Book[]>(url)
  .pipe(
   tap(_ => this.log(`fetched order for name=${user}`)),
   catchError(this.handleError<Book[]>('getBooks', []))
 );
}
```

Is working to.

When I try to use Postman or Swagger I see responde.

P.S when I coppy address on debug from:

```
const url = `${this.orderUrl}/name/${user}`;
```

And try in postman added Book in JSON:

```
{
 "bookID": 4,
 "title": "string2",
 "author": "strin2g",
 "isbn": "stri2ng"
 }
```

I have responde.

Comment: Are you sure your `url` strings are correct? Your code doesn't seem to be correctly URL-encoding parameters and route-values. Also you should never use `any` in TypeScript.

Comment: When I coppy and paste to Postman from debug and add Book is ok. Ok I didn't notice of this any. I think this same but I can't find solution. But other Url is working.

Comment: I'll bet money you're not subscribing anywhere to the calls to the API to fire.

Comment: No. I have:   addToOrder(book: Book): void {
    this.orderService.addToOrder("a", book)
          .subscribe(book => {
            this.books.filter(u => u !== book);;
    });
  } 
I se error 405 : UserService: addToOrder failed: 405 Http failure response for https://localhost:7216/api/orders: 405 OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I have a answer. I havae a:

```
   const url = `${this.orderUrl}/name/${user}`;
return this.http.post<Book>(this.orderUrl, book, this.httpOptions)
```

But must be:

```
   const url = `${this.orderUrl}/name/${user}`;
return this.http.post<Book>(url, book, this.httpOptions)
```

Sory for problem. I didn't notice it.

Answer (score 0):

By default POST method parameters must all be in the request body *(`FromBody`)*.

GET method parameters must all be in the request query *(`FromUri`)*.

To change this behavior, you need to add Parameters Bindings.

[.net Parameter Binding docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

## Changes

```cs
[HttpPost("name/{name}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Book>> PostOrder(
    [FromUri] string name, 
    [FromBody] Book book)
{
    // CODE
}
```

Comment: Mayby problem is in it, but when I change to: public async Task<ActionResult<Book>> PostOrder([System.Web.Http.FromUri]string name, [System.Web.Http.FromBody]Book book) this no working to. And why is working in postman whenever?

Comment: you are setting the address to "mydomain/name/{name}". Open the browser, do the actions to the page make the requestion and check URL _(Check RoutePrefixAttribute on Controller)_.

Comment: the URL must be the same as the one you use on Postman.